# How to add in new items that don't fit in existing menus?

Tags: layout, mobile-application, menu

I have a mobile app with the general layout of having a menu menu, a queue that needs to be easily accessible and show a list of items in or previously in queue and any statuses, and a submit button front-and-center.

The menu and queue options open flyout side menus that work well. The problem comes in with adding in additional actions like clearing the form. One more item at the bottom is fine, but get more than a couple and it gets unwieldy. It doesn't make sense under menu because that houses account and general app settings and not actions pertaining to the current form.

A vertical ellipsis option seems a little out of place beside submit, and adding another menu near the top also seems overwhelming. Any thoughts on how to organize the navigation in a sensible way to accommodate more form-specific actions?

[image: General layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a "form Tools bar", as an example: delete or start again, go to previous field, jump to next field and save form:

[image]